# Embedded Youtube videos slowwww things down

Tags: php, javascript, youtube, embedded-video

I'm creating a site with a lot of embedded Youtube videos, but it seems the video players take a while to load. Is there a way I could speed things up?

If this is not possible, then how do you embed just the thumbnails and load the videos when a user clicks on the thumbnail?

Comment: Why does it matter? Does it make the page unresponsive or the layout change unexpectedly?

Comment: It slows down load time. Also, I find that sometimes the video images disappear when I scroll or click certain buttons.

Comment: What does this have to do with 'java'?

Answer (score 1):

About your first question:

You cannot control the load speed because the videos are not hosted on your server but on Youtube's one.

About your second question:

You can check this address in order to find out how to extract the thumbnails from the youtube videos: http://www.reelseo.com/youtube-thumbnail-image/

After that you can load the youtube video on onclick using Ajax or simple redirect to a separate page where video is positioned.